# Visual Studio 2013 issue in the WebJobs deployment logic with .resx

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

I have a solution with two projects: a website and a webjob.

I've added the webjob to the website with the "add existing project as a webjob" VS functionality.

The webjob is an extremely simple console project that prints a "Hello World" in two languages using .resx files

Everything works ok when I launch the console project in my local machine.

The problem occurs when I publish the website (it doesn't matter if I publish on the file system, azure website, etc., the same thing happens): the webjob is published to the website AppData folder as suposed, but it doesn't include the localization folders. The result is that the published webjob in the AppData website print the "Hello World" twice, but in the neutral language.

I've shared a repo that you can find here: https://github.com/subgurim/WebJobLocalizationTests. You only need to clone it, execute the console project to check the correct behaviour and then publish the website. You'll see the webjob in the AppData folder, execute it and you'll see the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Can you check via FTP it the necessary files were deployed?

Comment: I've published the website in the local system, so I've checked that the locatization directories (/es, /it, /fr...) are not published in the AppData/XXXX/MyWebJob directory. I've also published via FTP and via git to azure, and the same problem happens :(

Comment: Please have a look at this msdn forum entry: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/7aa1bd34-5c44-4922-80d4-653ad43eb170/resources-localization-for-webjob?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview It seems that you have catched a known bug.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I did it, I'm actually the one who made the last comment